# WPF Combobox isEditable bind entry to list

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, combobox

I have a combobox, I want the user to be able to enter their selection into the combobox. I have it set to editable which works but the user can enter any entry they want. Though say the list contains Dog, Cat, Bird. The user can enter Snaked instead. How can I stop this?

```
        <ComboBox IsEditable="True" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5,3,0,0"
                  Text="{Binding Model.Number}" ItemsSource="{Binding DList}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Model.Number}"
                  IsEnabled="{Binding EnableComboBox}" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top">

        </ComboBox>
```

Comment: I haven't understood 'I want the user to be able to enter the option they want because of the length' this sentence. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: So you want one entry in the combobox that when it gets selected the combobox becomes editable?

Comment: updated for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it Read only, this will stop the typing feature. If in VS you can do this in the properties section of the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop this?

Set the `IsEditable` property to false and the `IsTextSearchEnabled` property to true:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding DList}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" />
```

It doesn't make much sense to have an editable `ComboBox` with a `TextBox` if you only want the user to be able to select something that is actually present in the Items collection.

If the `ComboBox` is bound to an `IEnumerable<T>` you could set the `TextSearch.TextPath` property to the name of a property of the type `T`:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Animals}" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" TextSearch.TextPath="AnimalName" />
```